# React Native JS Debugging/Hot Reloading not working on physical device

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a basic React Native app generated from the `react-native init sampleApp` CLI command. I have not yet included any code/plugins/libraries etc.

It works fine for hot reloading in the virtual simulator, but when deployed to a physical device on the same network (even with the same code with localhost swapped for the computers IP address in RCTWebSocketExecutor).

When I deploy to device and enable **Debug JS Remotely**, my browsers debugger page (at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui) picks up the connection but throws an error:

`debuggerWorker.js:18 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/C3B39D18-FF73-4666-A5CB-D4BD221F2BF8/sampleApp.app/main.jsbundle' failed to load.`

Has anyone any experience dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
```

it show Dev menu in physical device